# OkHttpResponse - parse received chunked data which is text/html

Tags: android, okhttp

I am having a problem with parsing chunked response from the server. 
This is how I am creating the request (simulating form submission) with post.

```
val requestBody = MultipartBody.Builder()
  .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
  .addFormDataPart("key1","value1")
  .build()


val requestBuilder = Request.Builder()
  .url(formActionUrl)
  .method("POST",requestBody)
  .build()

val response = okHttpClient
                .newCall(requestBuilder)
                .execute()
```

The problem for me is here, when I try to read the body source.

```
 if(isChunked){
   val responseBody = response.body
   val source = responseBody!!.source ()
   val buffer = Buffer () 
   val builder = java.lang.StringBuilder()
   while (!source.exhausted ()) {
      val readBytes = source.read (buffer, Long.MAX_VALUE)
      val data = buffer.readString (Charset.forName ("UTF-8"))
      builder.append(data)
   }
   Log.d("builder",builder.toString())
}
```

This is logging some glyphs. And I am not able to get the HTML data.

**Debugged:** 
I have tried to replicate the exact call with Postman, and I am successfully getting the HTML response, however, when debugging with Stetho I am not seeing the HTML response (response tab is empty), even though I am getting 200 successful code.

I am guessing I will have to read the chunkes somehow, perhaps custom interceptor or something. Can anybody give me some hint on how to parse/read the source from the response? - Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a while I figured out on my own. Basically what I had to do is to read the chunks out of the source and parse them which were encoded with Gzip (encoding can be found in the response headers - **Content-Encoding**)
So basically this is the code:

```
   val isChunked = isChunked(response.headers)
   val subtype = responseBody.contentType()!!.subtype.toLowerCase() //html
   val type = responseBody.contentType()!!.type.toLowerCase() //text
   val charset = responseBody.contentType()!!.charset().toString()//UTF-8

   val buffer = Buffer()
   if(isChunked) {
      while (!source.exhausted()) {
         source.read(buffer, 8192)
      }
      source.close()
   }

   if(subtype.contains("html")) {
      val pureHtml = GZIPInputStream(buffer.inputStream())
         .bufferedReader(UTF_8)
         .use { it.readText() }
         buffer.flush()
      webview.loadData(pureHtml,"$type/$subtype",charset)
   }else{
      //handle diff types
   }
```

Please bear in mind that the response body can be read only once. See bellow according to the square docs:

> Response bodies must be closed and may be consumed only once

Also from reading the docs, square recommends closing the response and the body, as the could potentially slow down the app.